# SecKeychainItemDelete returns -67701 (errSecInvalidRecord) on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I have a program built with Xcode 3.2.5 on a Mac 10.6 system, the program needs to add to and remove items from the system keychain. It runs well on Mac OS X 10.6 but on 10.7, The call to SecKeychainItemDelete returned error code -67701 which is not defined in 10.6 SDK. After some googling I found -67701 (errSecInvalidRecord) is newly added in 10.7 SDK. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem. This happens because the keychain api caches SecKeychainItemRef object every time one of [SecKeychainFindInternetPassword](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeychainFindInternetPassword) and [SecKeychainFindGenericPassword](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeychainFindGenericPassword) methods is called. So, whenever you have called any of these two methods be sure to clear the api cache using the method [SecKeychainItemFreeAttributesAndData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeychainItemFreeAttributesAndData). Also release the SecKeychainItemRef object using CFRelease.

Comment: Very helpful. For me, it seemed that keeping more than one SecKeychainItemRef's in memory (i.e. in my KeychainItem wrapper class member variable) that pointed to the same Keychain item, triggered this issue. I ended up CFRelease'ing immediately after retrieving the data. Still seems kind of lame to me.

Answer (score 2):

To answer a super old question: I think this is because of the new sandboxing features in OS X Lion. I think the solution is to sign your app and add enablements for the Keychain.

Source: [TunnelBlick - an OSS VPN tunnel - suggests this is the problem](http://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/issues/detail?id=202)